# Need to replace one table for another (with the same type, but other data) in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a copy of my table, after this I make some commands on my table (base, not on copy) like insert/delete/update, and I have problem when I want to replace my table for my copy. Select into give me error. When I try to drop table and recreate with copy, I got error that I can't delete table with foreign keys. I don't have any other idea, can somebody help me ? :)

Comment: The error message says it all, your original table is referenced by a foreign key. You shouldn't drop that table without considering the consequences.

Comment: Do not try to recreate a table using SELECT .. INTO syntax. This approach will not recreate any indexes, constraints, relationships etc. that were defined on the original table. You should use the script generation functions in Management Studio or other tools to ensure that you have a script available to exactly recreate objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't drop table with FK, but you can

1. Drop the constraints
2. Create temporary table
3. Copy your data in the temporary table
4. Truncate the initial table
5. Recreate the constraints in the initial table.
6. Copy your temporary table in your initial table.